# Creating a Temperature Application in Dr. Java

Tags: java

Create a Temperature application that prompts the user for the temperature each day for the
past 5 days and then displays the lowest temperature of the five days, the highest temperature
of the five days and the average temperature. The application output should look similar to the
followings : 
Enter the high temperature on day 1: 89
Enter the high temperature on day 2: 65
Enter the high temperature on day 3: 22
Enter the high temperature on day 4: 78
Enter the high temperature on day 5: 63
The average high temperature is 63.4
The lowest temperature is 22.0
The highest temperature is 89.0

This is basically what I have:

```
             System.out.print ("Enter the temperature on day 1: ");
             double day1 = kbReader.nextDouble();
             System.out.print ("Enter the temperatre on day 2: ");
             double day2 = kbReader.nextDouble();
             System.out.print ("Enter the temperature on day 3: ");
             double day3 = kbReader.nextDouble();
             System.out.print ("Enter the temperature on day 4: ");
             double day4 = kbReader.nextDouble();
             System.out.print ("Enter the temperature on day 5: ");
             double day5 = kbReader.nextDouble();

             double average = day1 + day2 + day3 + day4 + day5;
             double finalaverage = average/5;
             System.out.println ("The average high temperature is " +  finalaverage);
```

I want to know how to find the highest and lowest temperture using a loop

Comment: Instead of storing them in individual variables, store them in an array. Apply a for loop with two high and min variables.

Comment: do you mind explaining to me how you would do that? I've just learned this unit and I cannot seem to grasp it well

Comment: I would not minding helping you, but give it a try with the above approach, If there are any issues, please come back.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this code Works fine in java

```
            double temp[]=new double[5];
            double avgTemp=0;
            double highTemp=0;
            double lowTemp=0;

            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                System.out.print ("Enter the temperature on day "+(i+1)+" :");
                temp[i]=sc.nextDouble();
            }

            //for calculation average temp
            double sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                sum+=temp[i];
            }

            System.out.println("Average temp is "+(sum/5));

       //for calculation high temp
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(temp[i]>highTemp){
            highTemp=temp[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("hightemp is "+highTemp);
    lowTemp=temp[0];
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
        if(temp[i]<lowTemp){
            lowTemp=temp[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("hightemp is "+lowTemp);
```